# Performance issue when drawing Polygones on Api Map V2 Android

Tags: android, api, google-maps, optimization, polygon

Map is very slow when I try to display lots of Polygones on android

Here is the following code that displays approximately 1000 polygones on GoogleMap.

```
List<LatLng> list = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
for (int i = 0; i < 33; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 33; j++) {
            list.add(new LatLng(46.961511 + (0.001 * i), 4.866943+ (0.001 * j)));
            list.add(new LatLng(46.961511 + (0.001 * i) + 0.001, 4.866943 + (0.001 * j)));          
            list.add(new LatLng(46.961511 + (0.001 * i)+ 0.001, 4.866943+ 0.001+ (0.001 * j)));         
            list.add(new LatLng(46.961511 + (0.001 * i), 4.866943+ 0.001+ (0.001 * j)));
            addPolygoneToMap(list);
            list.clear();
        }
 }
 private void addPolygoneToMap (List<LatLng> latLngList) {
        mMap.addPolygon(new PolygonOptions()
                .addAll(latLngList)
                .fillColor(Color.BLUE)
                .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                .strokeWidth(3));
 }
```

On ApiMapV1 I was displaying more than 2 000 polygones overlay.

The problem is NOT creating the polygons, it's scrolling over the map.

How can I solve this problem? What am I doing it wrong and how can I optimize this?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: I goofed and didn't realize that Google Maps for Android doesn't let you make custom maps, as you can with Google Maps for Web.

Google Maps can't handle that may polygons.  You can get around the problem with Google Maps for Web, but to show that many polygons, from a practical standpoint, you will need to generate tiles.  So you would need to redo your app as a Web page instead of a native app.

There is lots of material out there on how to make a map with custom map tiles.  See

- http://econym.org.uk/gmap/custommap.htm
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/maptypes#CustomMapTypes

I also have a blog post on ways to increase the rendering speed of tiles, stackoverflow isn't letting me post another link.  Search for 
   sherwood optimizing map tile generation

Good luck!

Comment: all the link you gave me concerned Javascript. I have this problem on android. There are TilesOverlays on android but it looks like it's not what i need. Tiles are images you place on an x,y position on the map. But i need the color of the border, and center to be variable, and also the width and height. 
Tell me if i'm wrong but it's not possible with tiles?

Comment: I am so embarrassed.  You are right.  I was assuming that maps for android had basically the same features as maps for web.  I just looked at the Android API, and nope, it doesn't allow you to use your own tiles.